# Print при изменении переменной

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть вот такой код который считает данные из всего Лог файла(Лог файл постоянно обновляется), и записывает в переменную только результат суммы последнего подсчета.

```
   import re
    import operator
    last = operator.itemgetter(-1)
    a = open('14.04.2019.log', 'r')
    while a:
        for i in a:
            res = re.findall(r': (\d+) \+ (\d+)$', i)    
            if res:
                a_list = [(sum(map(int, *res)))]
        b = last(a_list)
```

как реализовать print переменной когда она изменится, то бишь при каждом изменении выводилось число. И в итоге получалось к примеру

```
123
6869
457
235
```

Comment: Если мой ответ Вам помог, обозначьте его, пожалуйста, как принятый нажатием на `v` под счётчиком голосов

Answer (score 1):

То, что у Вас вверху написано, работать, к сожалению, не будет. `a` это дескриптор открытого файла. Чтобы достать оттуда построчно текст вашего лога, следует использовать `a.readline()`

Так как в ответе на Ваш предыдущий вопрос я уже привел вариант кода, вот его и доработаем:

```
    import re

    r_pattern = re.compile(': (\d+) \+ (\d+)$')

    # Предыдущее найденное число
    prev_value = None

    with open('test.log','rt',encoding='utf-8') as f:
        while True:
            line = f.readline()
            if not line: break

            match = re.search(r_pattern, line)
            if match:
                value = int(match.group(1)) + int(match.group(2))

                if not value == prev_value: # Сравниваем с предыдущим
                    prev_value = value # Обновляем предыдущее число на новое
                    print(value) # И печатаем
```

Ещё пару моментов по Вашему коду:

```
a_list = []
while ...
    for ...
        if res:
            a_list.append(sum(map(int, *res)))
```

И почему бы не?

```
b = a_list[-1]
```